# Need help understanding basic buffer overflow

Tags: ida, elf, exploit, patch-reversing, buffer-overflow

So I have this sample problem that I need to buffer overflow. Its an elf file that require to be run on a separate terminal then using "nc localhost 'port' " on a separate terminal we can see the input.

On IDA I have

[image]

which from some reason I dont understand what Im looking for so I tried using a buffer overflow technique and I got

[image]

and in the other terminal I got

[image]

I tried for days looking around for techniques and understanding how to solve this problem but im always reaching dead ends.

Here is a link to the elf file: https://we.tl/t-vlqS6LwqlB

Comment: Welcome to RE.SE! Did you consider that it is a 64bit system? You could also have a look at the stack with gdb when breaking at the return statement, looking for the 0x41's

Comment: @Nordwald Could please clarify the steps?